# Suitable and Compatible Databases for various platforms

Tags: java, android, database, windows-mobile, javafx-2

Which database is compatible and suitable for Windows Mobile, Android & Java Desktop application using Java ? I want to use a single DB for all the 3 platforms using Java. I plan to develop application using JavaFX2.0.

I found MySQL compatible with all. SQLLite is not very well compatible with Win Mob OR Android. Waht are your suggestions for the above ?

Comment: *"I found MySQL compatible with all."* MySQL *server* on Windows Mobile?!

Comment: I've got a WM 5.0 app running SQLite. You need to use the binaries (a tad newer), not the installer (has a minor flaw making it incompatible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite is probably the best platform to run on Windows Mobile, Android, and Java.  SQLite is very compatible with Windows Mobile.  I've used it both natively and through the newer System.Data.SQLite ADO.NET provider.  You have to poke around to find the good version for .NET use with the Compact Framework.  It's available for download [here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki).

Comment: Can I distribute SQLite with the application and access it locally without using Server ?